# PHP: Get file sent from DefaultHTTPClient Android

Tags: php, android, file-upload, http-post

I send a file via HTTPPost in android:

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
        reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

In PHP how do I get the file?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure where your file would end up on the server. As far as I can tell you won't be able to access it using the [$_FILES array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

I would suggest that you try to upload the file to your server the same way as it would be uploaded using an HTML form. If you do it that way you can handle the file upload using the [$_FILES array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php). Judging from [similar questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525982/uploding-file-on-server-using-post-from-android-giving-exception) there's a ton of code you need to write to get this to work though... BUT [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) has good support for file uploads out of the box:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.png");
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
try {
    params.put("profile_picture", myFile);
    client.post("http://www.yourserver.com/upload.php", params, responseHandler);
}
catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    // handle
}
```

Comment: AsynchHttpClient does not exist in android. Do I need to install a jar file?

Comment: Yes, it's a very popular third party library. There's a big green download button on the page I linked. Download the jar file, put it in  the /libs folder of you project and make sure it's included (a simple refresh of your project in Eclipse should be sufficient I think)